# Can winbind influence name resolution in Linux

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, hosts-file, resolv.conf, srv-record

I have to Linux boxes on vagrant, the have the same /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/hosts, but one is using winbind to do SSO with Active Directory. When I try to resolve the domain controllers with:

```
dig SRV _ldap._tcp.wonga.com
```

on the server with winbind I have a connection timeout. Normal name resolution works fine though. I do not have nscd running. I wonder is winbind can influence name resolution and if only /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/hosts are involved in name resolution. /etc/nssswitch.conf is:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat winbind
group:          compat winbind
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

If I remove winbind in passwd and group nothing changes and in the end nsswitch.conf line involved in name resolution should be only this:

```
hosts:          files dns
```

Answer (score 0):

Winbind has no effect here on DNS lookups.

I can successfully make the same DNS query against our AD domain controller.

We also don't run nscd, and my nss file looks the same as yours.

Is it possible that NAT in VirtualBox is having an effect. Does switching to bridging help?